# How to install psycopg2 for use in HDInsight PySpark Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, azure, psycopg2, jupyter, azure-hdinsight

I need to "import psycopg2" as part of my PySpark script.

Per the [documentation](https://notebooks.azure.com/faq#upload_data):

> !pip install
>   psycopg2

but that results in a syntax error (as any ! command does).

I was able to install in an SSH session for /usr/bin/anaconda/bin/python, but it appears Jupyter may be using a different different environment?

I even tried forcing

> os.environ["PYTHONPATH"]

in the notebook but no luck, by which I mean from a cell in the notebook:

- import psycopg2 results in an error that module can't be found
- help("modules") does not show psycopg2
- help("modules psycopg2") results in the following error:

> ```
> Here is a list of matching modules.  Enter any module name to get more help.
>
> Failed to write user configuration file.
> Please submit a bug report.
> sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.psycopg2 - .. dialect:: postgresql+psycopg2
> sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.psycopg2cffi - .. dialect:: postgresql+psycopg2cffi
> ```

Comment: I encountered the same problem. Do you find a solution for this?

Comment: I got a response that %%bash should be used followed by the command on the following line, but by then we had already moved on

Answer (score 0):

Did you make a typo? Your text was 'pyscopg2' not 'psycopg2'

```
!pip install psycopg2
```

For Python 3.5 and Python 2.7 is installed already on Azure Notebooks.

Comment: yes, typo in the SO post, not in the notebook. The rest of the behavior remains - as does the error when trying to execute a console statement prefaced by !